# ASP.NET Core - Serve index.html on all routes without rewriting the URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

creating an ASP.NET Core api. Is it possible to serve a SPA index.html on all paths that don't begin with "/api" without redirecting and rewriting the URL (thereby losing the URL for the SPA).

Answer (score 1):

The SPA middleware that is used in both the Angular and the React templates for ASP.NET Core does exactly that. It will serve all remaining requests to the configured `DefaultPage`, defaulting to `/index.html`.

Just add the `UseSpa()` call as the *latest* middleware within the Startup’s `Configure`, after the `UseEndpoint()` call:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // configure the path to the folder where the static `index.html` is
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "YourStaticFileDirectory"));

// serve static files
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider
});

// return index.html if no route matched
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider
});
```